# How can I quickly assign placeholder text to all select elements that are not already selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, placeholder

I want to be able to specify a HTML5-style placeholder text in my select inputs, like so:

```
<select name='blah' placeholder='select one'>
```

But, I need the placeholder text to NOT be a selectable element, and not show up at all if the select contains an `<option>` that is already selected. On the other hand, I knwo some browsers remember the last selection and automatically jump to it on a page reload - that should not count as an option being already selected. OK to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than it looks - just iterate over each select element, adding a readonly disabled selected non-displaying option with the text value of the placeholder attribute of the containing select... Ok, maybe it's not that easy! In any case, here's how to do it:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('select[placeholder]:not(:has(option[selected]))').each(function(i, o){
        $(o).append($('<option>').
            attr('readonly', 'readonly').
            attr('selected', 'selected').
            attr('disabled', 'disabled').
            css('display', 'none').
            text($(o).attr('placeholder'))
        );
    });
});
```

· Edited to use A. Wolff's suggestion of a more complicated css selector instead of an if statement.

Comment: Isn't it enough: `$('select:not(:has(option))').append(function(){
    return $('<option>', {text:$(this).attr('placeholder')}).hide();
});`

Comment: @A.Wolff No, hide isn't enough. In some browsers hidden options can still be selected by keyboard, so it has to be disabled. Can't remember why the readonly is required.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

```
$("[name='blah']").select2({
    placeholder: "select one",
    allowClear: true
});
```